# ImportError: Module 'django.contrib' does not contain a 'Advisor' class. ------- why am I getting this error

Tags: python-3.x, django

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\threading.py", line 1016, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\threading.py", line 953, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\mgkco\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\mgkco\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 125, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "C:\Users\mgkco\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 87, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "C:\Users\mgkco\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 398, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "C:\Users\mgkco\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper      
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\mgkco\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\mgkco\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 91, in populate        
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "C:\Users\mgkco\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 225, in create
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Module 'django.contrib' does not contain a 'Advisor' class.
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting that error because you, for some reason, have `django.contrib.Advisor` in your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting.

Did you maybe mean `django.contrib.admin`?

Comment: INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.Advisor',
    'django.contrib.auth',          #Core authentication framework and its default models.
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',  #Django content type system (allows permissions to be associated with models).
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    #'rest_framework',
    'Advisor',
    'User',

]   ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------this is my INSTALLED_APPS setting

Comment: As I suspected - that first entry is `django.contrib.Advisor`; it should be `django.contrib.admin`.